# Как задать имя потока, класс которого имплементирует интерфейс Runnable в Java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Имеется класс `Task`, реализующий интерфейс `Runnable`, который (класс) в будущем станет потоком. Как задать `id` для этого класса, чтобы использовать в дальшейнем.
Вот, что я использую. Создаю класс `Task` с конструктором, который задает `id`, и переопределяю метод `public String toString()`:

```java
public class Task implements Runnable {
    private final int id;

    static Blocker blocker = new Blocker();

    public Task(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        blocker.waitingCall();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Thread (" + id + ")";
    }
}
```

Поток создаю с помощью `ExecutorService`:

```java
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    exec.execute(new Task(i));
}
```

Далее хочу в другом классе в синхронизированном методе вывести `id` потока, который будет находится в данном методе с помощью `Thread.currentThread()` вот так:

```java
synchronized void waitingCall() {
        try {
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                wait();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " from class \"" + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\" waiting...Zzz");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("A permissible way out");
        }
    }
```

Но на выходе получаю вот такую строку:
`Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main] from class "Blocker" waiting...Zzz`, а не ожидаемую `Thread (id)`. Почему так происходит? Интересует именно способ задания имени для потока, который создается с помощью реализации интерфейса `Runnable`, а не через наследование класса `Thread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть всего два способ задания имени:

1. через конструктор класса `Thread`
2. изменить имя уже созданного потока с помощью `Thread.setName`.

При использовании пула потоков, первый способ не годится, потому что потоки повторно используются для запуска разных задач. Более того, пул создает поток вне контекста задачи, т.е. он еще не знает какую задачу он будет исполнять, и соответственно не может использовать его имя.

Вот это из вопроса неверно, когда используется пул потоков:

> Имеется класс Task, реализующий интерфейс Runnable, который (класс) в будущем станет потоком.

Экземпляр Task не станет потоком, когда его запустите с помощью executor-а. Executor воспользуется своим потоком, который он создал, и тот существующий поток вызовет метод `Task.run`. После этого executor вызовет `Task.run` у следующего экземпляра опять же в существующем потоке. Грубо говоря поток `executor`-а исполняет цикл:

```
  Runnable task;
  while((task = queue.getNextTask() != null) {
    task.run();
  }
```

И потому не работает способ с использованием `ThreadFactory`.

Можно изменить имя текущего потока так на уровне задачи:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    String oldName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    try {
       Thread.currentThread().setName(toString());
       blocker.waitingCall();
    } finally {
       Thread.currentThread().setName(oldName);
    }
}
```

Второй вариант - это создать свой executor, нужно наследоваться от `ThreadPoolExecutor` и переопределить в нем методы `beforeExecute` и `afterExecute` (если нужно восстановить имя):

```
class NamingThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
  protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) { 
     t.setName(r.toString());
  }
}
```

Потом использовать свой класс вместо `Executors` (точно так же как делается в `Executors.newCachedThreadPool`):

```
ExecutorService exec = new NamingThreadPoolExecutor(
        0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
        60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

В этом случае сами задачи модифицировать не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал создавать `Thread` через `ThreadFactory`, тогда у вас будет возможность контролировать процесс создания нити и в этот момент задавать ему нужное имя, например:

```
class SimpleThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
   public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
     return new Thread(r, r.toString());
   }
 }

 ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new SimpleThreadFactory());
```

Comment: Боюсь это не будет работать так как нужно. Во-первых, сюда передается совсем другой `Runnable`, и это не будет наша задача, которую мы передали в `execute`. Это основной метод потока из пула, он делает гораздо больше чем просто вызывает `run`, задачи которую мы запускаем. Потоки же повторно используются, если есть свободный, то он будет использован и `newThread` вообще не будет вызван.

Comment: @RomanKonoval `execute(new Task(i))` передаст `new Task(i)` в `ThreadFactory` и он вернет ему хэндл на созданный `Thread` - так что все должно сработать. Давайте посмотрим что скажет ТС - пусть проверит, тем более, что реализовать это довольно просто

Comment: Вы сильно ошибаетесь. Если бы все работало, так как вы говорите, то потоки нельзя было бы возвращать в пул. После выполнения метода `run` поток завершается. А нужно чтоб продолжал работать, поэтому в пуле выполняются специальные Runnable, которые внутри берут из очереди те Runnable, которые мы передаем executor-у.

Comment: Мы можем спорить до хрипоты, рассудит только эксперимент/код/лог, все остальное трата времени :)

Comment: @Barmaley, без создания класса, наследующего класс `Thread`, задать имя потоку невозможно?

Comment: @Jake я считаю, что можно, а Роман считает, что я неправ - проверьте сами, код приведен в ответе

Comment: Задать имя потоку без создания класса можно - пользуйтесь конструктором потока. Я выше писал не об этом, а том, что подход описаный в этом ответе не решает задачу поставленную в вопросе. А именно используя `ThreadFactory` вы не получите имя из Runnable, который передается в `execute`.